# how to display float value in mfc application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, win32gui

hi i want to pass a float value that compute the execution time of the program to the edit box on the dialog of mfc application.

i already have the equation

```
clock_t stime, etime;
float t = ((etime - stime) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

i'm using the following to pass integer values

```
parameter->results_dialog->m_atteptsEdit.SetWindowText( itoa(Attempts, val, 10 ) );
```

Comment: So you're asking how to convert from float to  a string that SetWindowText will use?

Answer (score 2):

Use CString::Format() to format the float and pass that to the SetWindowText function.

```
clock_t stime, etime;
float t = ((etime - stime) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
CString str;
str.Format("%f", t);
parameter->results_dialog->m_atteptsEdit.SetWindowText( str );
```